# Watir-webdriver gem in cloud9ide

Tags: watir-webdriver, cloud9-ide

Below is the error I receive in the Cloud9 IDE when attempting to run my very basic watir test script

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto 'http://apple.com'
```

-- BEGIN ERROR --

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/binary.rb:120:in `path': Could not find Firefox binary (os=linux). Make sure Firefox is installed or set the path manually with Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path= (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)                                                     
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/binary.rb:53:in `execute'                                              
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/binary.rb:34:in `start_with'                                           
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:70:in `start_silent_and_wait'                              
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:35:in `block in launch'                                    
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/socket_lock.rb:20:in `locked'                                          
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:32:in `launch'                                             
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:24:in `initialize'                                           
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:31:in `new'                                                   
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:31:in `for'                                                   
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'                                                                 
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.10/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'                                                        
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/test_puppies/first_script.rb:3:in `new'                                                                                                             
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/test_puppies/first_script.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: not familiar with Cloud9, but I would assume it's all just a GUIless server. Watir requires an actual browser to be present and bootable. Maybe try mechanize instead?

Comment: It looks like cloud9 doesn't play nicely, at first glance, with `xvfb`, a virtual frame buffer which is required to run firefox without a display.  I did the following on my c9 instance: `sudo apt-get install firefox`, `sudo apt-get install xvfb` and added these lines to my `Gemfile`: `gem "headless"` and `gem "watir-webdriver"` and ran `bundle install`. Then I followed the instructions at http://watirwebdriver.wordpress.com/headless/ and had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After a lot of trial and error I found running  `Install firefox and xvfb: sudo apt-get install firefox xvfb` fixed it for me.

I should note that I am using the [headless](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless) gem you mentioned above and this code on the [watirwebdriver.com](http://watirwebdriver.com/headless/) website.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'headless'
headless = Headless.new
headless.start
b = Watir::Browser.start 'www.google.com'
puts b.title
b.close
headless.destroy
```